# How to execute shell script in remote server using Jenkins Active choice parameter groovy script?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to execute a shell scripts in a remote server over ssh using groovy scripts .

**Note: Source and Destination servers are passwordless authenticated**

Groovy Scripts  test.groovy:

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
//def proc = "sh test.sh".execute()
def proc = "sh test.sh".execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
println proc
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println sout
println serr
def final_output = sout.tokenize()
println final_output
return final_output
```

and my test.sh contains :

```
cd /Users/xyz/testing_directory

#show me list of files 
ssh xyz@10.56.45.67 'ls'
```

Now when I execute same using  groovy test.groovy then I am not getting any output.

**But if I am changing "ssh xyz@10.56.45.67 'ls'" line to only "ls" in test.sh it works and shows me list of files of same source servers .**

working example when removing ssh part from  test.sh

```
#show me list of files 
 ls
```

Now issue is groovy scripts unable to show outputs while connecting to remote server over ssh

**Note : ssh xyz@10.56.45.67 'ls' works fine in jenkins execute shell as well as terminal only not working in groovy scripts**

Please help me out and thanks in advance

Comment: Try to `return [seer]` if it's not empty. Use `try{...} catch (e){ return [e.toString()] }` for the whole script. This will add you error visibility. Because the only way to see the error - return it to drop-down .

Comment: seer is empty   if you see I used print statement and same test.sh file execution working from terminal not via groovy script.

Comment: println is not working in active choice. and i meant `return [serr]`

Comment: I will update the question part as it seems confused. Basically forget about Jenkins part let's assume it is normal groovy script we have to run it from terminal

Comment: Does the ssh command work from a shell without prompts or other issues?

Comment: if it's a usual groovy script try to replace `proc.consume & proc.wait` with `proc.waitForProcessOutput( sout, serr)` to wait for full result.

Comment: Yes ssh works and is password less authenticated to remote sever.Again I am written waitfororkill(1000)  anyway waitforprocess I will test out . But normal shell script works only not working when connecting to remote server using ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hit and trail I got solution .

thanks @daggett

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc = "ssh username@10.x.x.xx 'ls'".execute()

proc.waitForProcessOutput(sout, serr)
println proc
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println sout
println serr
def final_output = sout.tokenize()
println final_output
return final_output
```